Is there a way to use the arrow keys to move chart elements in Excel and PowerPoint by individual pixel?
Is there a way to move elements using the arrow keys (or the keyboard in general)? I find that the 'snap-to' feature snaps to edges that I don't want, or I often want to move things and fine tune them by the pixel, but it is too difficult to be precise using the mouse.

Different versions behave a bit differently, but for current Windows desktop versions, you can adjust things VERY precisely by zooming in.
Zooming to a specific spot can be clunky; the easiest way I've found is to use CTRL + scrollwheel if you're using a mouse. If using a touchpad, there's usually some multi-finger squeeze trickery you can use to zoom in.

Not sure about chart elements, but you can move most objects in PowerPoint by selecting them and then pressing the arrow keys.
And if you hold down Alt while dragging an object with the mouse, snap-to is temporarily turned off.
